# Can't export table structure with expdp, parameter full=X conflicts with tablespaces=X

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to export table schema with expdp,

```
expdp \'sys/XXXX as sysdba\' dumpfile=XXX.dmp logfile=XXXX.log content=METADATA_ONLY tablespaces=XXXX
```

And it fails with

```
ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
```

Then I added `full=Y` and it conflicts with tablespaces parameter:

```
ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
```

How can I export all schemas from specific tablespaces only?

Comment: Note that you should not be using expdp or impdp 'as sysdba'.  The documentation _very specifically_  says "

Note:

Do not start Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users. ".  Reference https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-D5455260-C28C-475F-9E0E-2BE227E7F0E3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted works fine.

```
[oracle@o81 ~]$ expdp \'/ as sysdba\' tablespaces=users content=metadata_only

Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Nov 14 12:48:17 2020
Version 19.9.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLESPACE_01":  "/******** AS SYSDBA" tablespaces=users content=metadata_only
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Master table "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLESPACE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SYS.SYS_EXPORT_TABLESPACE_01 is:
  /u01/app/oracle/homes/OraDB19Home1/rdbms/log/expdat.dmp
Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLESPACE_01" successfully completed at Sat Nov 14 12:48:43 2020 elapsed 0 00:00:26

[oracle@o81 ~]$
```

You get this error when the tablespace specirfied does not exist:

```
[oracle@o81 ~]$ expdp \'/ as sysdba\' tablespaces=users123456 content=metadata_only

Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Nov 14 12:50:16 2020
Version 19.9.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLESPACE_01":  "/******** AS SYSDBA" tablespaces=users123456 content=metadata_only
ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLESPACE_01" completed with 1 error(s) at Sat Nov 14 12:50:19 2020 elapsed 0 00:00:03

[oracle@o81 ~]$
```

Comment: You're right, the tablespace does not exist. The error message itself is quite misleading.